# Deriving by multiple Interfaces containing same members with different data types

Tags: c#, interface, derived

I have following situation:

```
using System.Data;

namespace TestClass
{
    //this is a class generated by a wsdl and may not be changed
    public partial class MyTableClass : DataTable
    {
        public MyRowClass this[int index]
        {
            get { return ((MyRowClass) (this.Rows[index])); }
        }

        public partial class MyRowClass : DataRow
        {
            protected internal MyRowClass(DataRowBuilder builder)
                : base(builder)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    //in this partial class I am able to extend the wsdl class by my own interfaces
    public partial class MyTableClass : IDetailTable
    {
        IDetailRow IDetailTable.this[int index]
        {
            get { return this[index]; }
        }

        public partial class MyRowClass : IDetailRow
        {
        }
    }

    public interface IBaseTable
    {
        IBaseRow this[int index] { get; }
    }

    public interface IDetailTable : IBaseTable
    {
        new IDetailRow this[int index] { get; }
    }

    public interface IBaseRow
    {
    }

    public interface IDetailRow : IBaseRow
    {
    }
     }
```

The first part is a class generated by a wsdl definition. I have no ability to change anything here.
I have many wsdl definition files, most are very similar. So I want to define common interfaces for all, which will make me handle them easier in my code.
So my idea was to extend them by a partial class definition like above.

But I get an error here, and I have no idea why and what I should do here:

> Error 1   'TestClass.MyTableClass' does not implement interface member 'TestClass.IBaseTable.this[int]'. 'TestClass.MyTableClass.this[int]' cannot implement 'TestClass.IBaseTable.this[int]' because it does not have the matching return type of 'TestClass.IBaseRow'.  c:\users\mag\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\TestClass\TestClass\Class1.cs    6   24  TestClass

Only the base interfaces are implemented, not the derived detail interfaces. But why?

Answer (score 0):

C# only supports single-inheritance, i.e., each class can only extend one from one superclass. However, you have `MyTableClass` extending `DataTable` in your first `partial` class, and `IDetailTable` in the second. That's what's causing the compilation error.

I think what your really trying to get at is that the second `partial` class should actually `extend` from the wsdl definition class. So I would change

```
public partial class MyTableClass : IDetailTable
```

to

```
public class MyAwesomeTableClass : MyTableClass
```

Comment: I am not really sure what you want to do, but I don't think this will work. The MyAwesomeTableClass will not be available in the wsdl class, and I could not change this class.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you currently have and what you want to do with it. What are the exact classes that cannot be changed, and what are the custom classes you want to extend from the unchangeable ones?